# Clicking outside modals in react-boostrap using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-bootstrap

I have a Modal which has the following code:

```
class CreateBookingModal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal show={this.props.showModal}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>{`${strings.createBookingModal.title} ${convertDateToString((this.props.bookingDate || new Date()))}`}</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    {strings.createBookingModal.body}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    {/* TODO */}
                    <Button onClick={this.props.onCancelBookingCreation}>{strings.createBookingModal.cancel}</Button>
                    <Button onClick={() => this.props.onCreateBooking(123, 123, 123)} bsStyle="primary">{strings.createBookingModal.save}</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

showModal and bookingDate are both injected using redux. Now, all is fine and well as long as I use the two buttons which I have bound two dispatch handlers. However, I would also like to close the modal (i.e. change the value of showModal to false by using onCancelBookingCreation), when either escape is pressed, or the person clicks outside the modal. Is there a (pretty) way to do this?

Comment: Where do you get this Modal from? If it's from material or bootstrap, it's likely that it already has the support

Comment: react-bootstrap, none of the props for the modal seem to be doing what I want.

Comment: Doesn't `onHide` do exactly what you want? The docs say about it: 
`A callback fired when the header closeButton or non-static backdrop is clicked. Required if either are specified.` 
Which sounds like exactly what you want to me. It is possible that you might need to set `backdrop=true` as well

Comment: I'm apparently an idiot, oversaw that prop the 10 times I went through the list. Wooooooooooops. Also this is what happens when you code at 4 am and have been up since 8 am.

Comment: Ok, glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create an action which will be dispatched when clicking on 'body' element (or any element that is the background of modal) this action should change state 'showModal' to false, and when clicked on modal you should use e.stopPropagation to stop click event from propagating to ~background element.